# How to programmatically find geo location of incoming http request?

Tags: java, .net, geolocation, ip

I know there are many online tool available but I want to write in house tool, references or how to go about it? Or even it can be done or is a mammoth task?

Comment: using the google geoip libraries?

Comment: This is pretty simple to do. check out this resource http://www.ip2location.com/html5geolocationapi.aspx

Comment: [http://ip-api.com/](http://ip-api.com/) , [https://ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io) , [https://geoip-db.com](https://geoip-db.com) etc They provide the data in various formats too (JSON/XML/CSV…). To get a good understanding of how to use this various services, reading their documentation helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a location database of all IP addresses. So, either you build a database yourself (a genuinely mammouth task) or you use an external service.

Some IP location services have have APIs so you can call then from your code.